# Kafka Connect Cluster does not load simple connector plugin

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I tried to load a simple Kafka connector in Connect Cluster.
I created jar for the connector and started Kafka Connect as a docker. In the logs I can see that it's loading the plugin. Docker mounts jar file properly.
However when calling http://localhost:8083/connector-plugins my custom connector is not on the list.

I have simply built and started docker-compose from this repo: https://github.com/riferrei/kafka-source-connector.
Avalable plugin list I have is:
`[{"class":"io.confluent.connect.activemq.ActiveMQSourceConnector","type":"source","version":"5.5.0"},{"class":"io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector","type":"sink","version":"5.5.0"},{"class":"io.confluent.connect.ibm.mq.IbmMQSourceConnector","type":"source","version":"5.5.0"},{"class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector","type":"sink","version":"5.5.0"},{"class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector","type":"source","version":"5.5.0"},{"class":"io.confluent.connect.jms.JmsSourceConnector","type":"source","version":"5.5.0"},{"class":"io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector","type":"sink","version":"5.5.0"},{"class":"io.confluent.connect.storage.tools.SchemaSourceConnector","type":"source","version":"5.5.0-ccs"},{"class":"org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector","type":"sink","version":"5.5.0-ccs"},{"class":"org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector","type":"source","version":"5.5.0-ccs"},{"class":"org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector","type":"source","version":"1"},{"class":"org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector","type":"source","version":"1"},{"class":"org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector","type":"source","version":"1"}]`

Does anyone have an idea what could be an issue that the connector is not on the list? Or a hint what could I check?

Comment: Docker mounts the JAR where? Did you put this in your  `plugin.path`?

Comment: Docker mounts jar in directory in ```plugin.path```  which is ```CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: '/usr/share/java'```

In docker-compose:
```./target/components/packages/you-kafka-connect-sample-0.1.0/you-kafka-connect-sample-0.1.0/lib:/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-sample```

Comment: Is that path on your host correct? f you inspect the content of the jar file(s) created for the connector from your target folder, do you find the class that you want?

Comment: yes, config was all correct. The problem was in IntelliJ config, I have started mvn commands using IDE and there in Project language level was set to Java 16.
After changing it to 8 connector was loaded by kafka connect

Comment: So it works now? Feel free to post your solution below as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was in IntelliJ config, I have started mvn commands using IDE and there in Project language level was set to Java 16.
After changing it to 8 connector (as matching in pom.xml) was loaded by kafka connect cluster.

Comment: You saved me a lot of time!

Comment: Similar problem, I configured Java 17 in my pom.xml, and Kafka Connect was running with Java 11. Thank you.